# Food safety when making Koji rice / kojikin

Tags: food-safety, rice

I want to understand the process by which koji rice is *not* effected by [Bacillus Cereus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacillus_cereus) et.al.

The basic instructions for fermenting your own koji rice is:

- Steam rice
- Let it cool to around 35℃
- Inoculate with Aspergillus Oryzae
- Keep the rice warm (34-36℃) for ~5 days

  - Occasionally separate and aerate the rice grains during this time.

Some government [food safety sites](https://www.nhs.uk/common-health-questions/food-and-diet/can-reheating-rice-cause-food-poisoning/) report issues with bacterial-caused toxicity if cooked rice is not cooled quickly before storage.  Obviously the fermentation procedure above purposefully keeps the cooked rice at a high room temperature.

Koji rice is often used in situations where it is not re-cooked (e.g.: Amazake, Sake).  Millions of people eat koji rice derived products every day without issue, so one must infer that it is a safe product.

Is there some biochemical process caused by the fungal growth of A.Oryzae that is preventing the growth of B.Cereus ?

Further reading: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/food-science/koji

Comment: I'd guess that it's a combination of acidification and breakdown of the rice starches, but I don't have references.

Comment: Why are you asking for "a biochemical process"? You seem to be hunting for a single reason, which likely doesn't exist. If you throw around a few orange seeds into a beech forest, you won't get an orange grove, not because there is a biochemical reaction, but because the environment is not suitable to be overtaken by the new species. This is how all fermentation works, you just fill the environmental niche with whatever you need, and so the usual pathogens can't get a foothold.

Comment: @rumtscho "Outcompetition by the desired culture which fills the environmental niche" certainly sounds like the "bio" part of a "biochemical process" to me.

Comment: @dbmag9 the word "biochemical" has a set meaning, actually. An example for a biochemical process would be  [glycolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis). I don't know if some biochemical process is prominent in the competition between A.Oryzae and B.Cereus, but statistically, that would be a rather unlikely case. The competition itself is, of course, matter of biology, as you pointed out :) but it would be classically studied by microbiologists and food technologists, not by biochemists.

Comment: @rumtscho - Well if we were discussing fermentation of say wine/beer, I would answer with something like:  "The yeast removes oxygen an acidifies the liquid, making the environment unsuitable to other microorganisms.".  To me, that's a biochemical process.  If "biochemical" is a reserved word, we can edit it to something else.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Kingsley there is no pressure on you to change the wording, especially since you already got a very nice answer. To give a background explanation on my earlier comments: in the meaning you just explained, "biochemical" does indeed apply, but it is vacuous. Everything that microbes do is a biochemical process, so asking if there is a bc process within A.Oryzae that changes the environment is tautological, and not interesting. I had interpreted your question as whether A.Oryzae causes a novel biochemical process in B.Cereus (which is almost never the case), and, interpreted generously...

Comment: ... to ask if A.Oryzae is in some way "intentionally" interfering with existing bc processes in B.Cereus - which is much more common, but still on the rare side as opposed to just living and metabolizing, and as a side effect changing the general parameters of the environment, as in your wine example. Now borcymcfood wrote that in this specific case, there is indeed such targeted secretion of antimicrobial compounds, which do disturb bc processes in B.Cereus. The whole thing is mostly a language/philosophical nitpick, which luckily shouldn't prevent an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biochemical processes for *A. oryzae* inhibiting the growth of *B. cereus* involves the production of a range of metabolites that exert antimicrobial properties [1,2,3,4]:

> *"The exAP-AO17 protein strongly inhibited pathogenic microbial strains, including pathogenic fungi, Fusarium moniliform var. subglutinans and Colletotrichum coccodes, and showed antibacterial activity against bacteria, including E. coli O157 and Staphylococcus aureus."*  *[1] Park et al.*

> *"Besides its potent secretion machinery, A. oryzae is a generous source of various secondary metabolites [...]. Many of the metabolites secreted by A. oryzae have different reported bioactivities such as anticancer, cytotoxicity, antimicrobial, antihypertensive, and antiviral activities (Table 2)."  [2] Daba et al.*

[image: A. oryzae metabolites]
*Table of metabolites from [Daba et al.](https://bioresourcesbioprocessing.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40643-021-00408-z/tables/2)*

A mutated strain of *A. oryzae* also produced an unknown compound with antimicrobial effect, suggesting antimicrobial potential outside of the stable domesticated strains:

> *"Over 3000 EMS-treated, putative mutant A. oryzae cultures were tested in the described screening assay for antibacterial activity. A single EMS-treated A. oryzae isolate, named CAL220, exhibited antibacterial activity in the screening assay as indicated by complete lack of visible MRSA growth in the assay." [3] Leonard et al.*

As you're aware, Koji itself is an inoculum rich in enzymes for further fermentation of soy and grains, but also contains easily digestible sugars derived from *A. oryzae* breaking down the rice [4]. Combined with the near-neutral pH (>6) throughout and increasing at the end of fermentation [5], Koji would be very hospitable to *B. cereus* without the antimicrobial metabolites. As only a relatively small amount of Koji is used for the second stage of fermentation, the concentration and effect of these metabolites is diluted, hence the need for added salt for pathogen inhibition for this stage.

[image: pH of koji fermentation]
*Figure of pH over time from [Chancharoonpong et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212670812000826/pdf?md5=fd0b3846628e69e7e001611549312d81&pid=1-s2.0-S2212670812000826-main.pdf)*

Given the innumerable regional strains of *A. oryzae* in koji manufacture, and other species of fungi involved, there are countless other undocumented metabolite compounds that we're only beginning to identify - and biochemists outside of the
field of food technology are very interested in these as well. [6]

But to simplify things, yes, there is a single (group of) biochemical process responsible for *A. oryzae* outcompeting *B. cereus*, and it's the production of antimicrobial compounds.

---

[1] *Isolation and Characterization of an Extracellular Antimicrobial Protein from Aspergillus oryzae.*
Seong-Cheol Park, Nae Choon Yoo, Jin-Young Kim, Hae Kyun Park, Byung Jo Chae, Song Yub Shin, Hyeonsook Cheong, Yoonkyung Park, and Kyung-Soo Hahm.
https://doi.org/10.1021/jf802373h

[2] *The ancient koji mold (Aspergillus oryzae) as a modern biotechnological tool.*
Ghoson M. Daba, Faten A. Mostafa & Waill A. Elkhateeb.
https://doi.org/10.1186/s40643-021-00408-z

[3] *Random Mutagenesis of the Aspergillus oryzae Genome Results in Fungal Antibacterial Activity.*
Cory A. Leonard, Stacy D. Brown, and J. Russell Hayman.
https://doi.org/10.1155%2F2013%2F901697

[4] *Fermentation and the microbial community of Japanese koji and miso: A review.*
Joanne G. Allwood Lara T. Wakeling David C. Bean.
https://doi.org/10.1111/1750-3841.15773

[5] *Enzyme Production and Growth of Aspergillus oryzae S. on Soybean Koji Fermentation.*
Chuenjit Chancharoonpong, Pao-Chuan Hsieh, Shyang-Chwen Sheu
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apcbee.2012.06.011

[6] *Medical Application of Substances Derived from Non-Pathogenic Fungi Aspergillus oryzae and A. luchuensis-Containing Koji.*
Hiroshi Kitagaki.
https://doi.org/10.3390%2Fjof7040243

Comment: Great Answer!   Reference `[4]` is a good read too.